# How to connect to a Wi-Fi network using Python on OS X?

Tags: python, macos, wifi, pyobjc

I want to connect to a Wi-Fi network using Python on OS X (10.11). Based on [CWInterface reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreWLAN/Reference/CWInterface_reference/) I figured out there is a `iface.associateToNetwork_password_error_()` method available, however when called it does not connect to the network nor it does cause any exception.

At the same time `iface.disassociate()` works correctly and disconnects WiFi.

This is the code I tried:

```
import objc

objc.loadBundle('CoreWLAN',
       bundle_path='/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreWLAN.framework',
       module_globals=globals())

iface = CWInterface.interface()

iface.associateToNetwork_password_error_(SSID, PASSWORD, None)
```

How can I connect to a specified network from Python on OS X and make sure the connection has been established?

Comment: What is `SSID`? It looks to me like that method takes a `CWNetwork` as its first parameter, but as far as I can tell you don't have an instance of one to give to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to successfully connect to my home network with the following:

```
import objc

objc.loadBundle('CoreWLAN',
                bundle_path = '/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreWLAN.framework',
                module_globals = globals())

iface = CWInterface.interface()

networks, error = iface.scanForNetworksWithName_error_('<Name Of Network>', None)

network = networks.anyObject()

success, error = iface.associateToNetwork_password_error_(network, '<Password Of Network>', None)
```

Two key things that I suspect you were missing:

1. You weren't passing in a `CWNetwork` as your first parameter.
2. You weren't checking return values (IE, `success` and `error` in the final call). They could have helped you with tracking down any other issues, perhaps.

Comment: I tried this way but I'm getting an error that I don't understand the reason:

ValueError: NSInvalidArgumentException - -[OC_PythonUnicode securityType]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc861fdc040

Comment: @TiagoBeviláqua - I haven't use macOS in a few years. It may be that some APIs have substantially changed. I'd suggest posting a new question if you need help (I don't think anyone besides me will be notified about your comment.)